# How to match & merge rows in Google Sheets if duplicate is found in column?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 Google Sheets that have similar data (let’s say, 10 columns). In one column, the data is the same on both sheets. The sheets aren’t ordered in any relevant way.

I want to combine both sheets so that the duplicate data will match (align on the same row), and the other, different data will match on the same row.

Ex. **Start with**:

`Company Name | E-mail Address
McDonald’s, contact@mcds.com
eBay, john@ebay.com
Google, greg@google.com`

**Merged with**:

`Company Name | E-mail Address
McDonald’s Corp, contact@mcds.com
Alphabet Inc., greg@google.com
eBay Inc., john@ebay.com`

**So that it becomes**:

`Company Name | E-mail Address | Company Name 2
McDonald’s Corp, contact@mcds.com, McDonald’s
Alphabet Inc., greg@google.com, Google
eBay Inc., john@ebay.com, eBay`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where to start. I've read something about arrays, but unsure how to properly execute this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you solve your problem as there is an infinite number of ways to solve it each entirely different to the context of how you have your spreadsheet set up, you can create helper columns for example but it is best if you provide us a very concrete and real example so we can provide an exact formula with an exact output. For example give us the most simplified test data to work with cell references etc. You can always share a google sheet here or take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use the `Unique` function to merge duplicate data. If you provide a more specific example I can give you more specifics.